# MVVM: ViewModel inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, mvvm

I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class DocumentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public virtual string TabHeader
    {
        get { return "Document"; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DATA> data;
    /// <summary>
    /// Source for Grid
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<DATA> Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set
        {
            data = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }
  // ...... a lot of properties and methods ....
}
```

I want `ProcurementViewModel` to inherit `DocumentViewModel`:

```
 public class ProcurementViewModel : DocumentViewModel
 {
    public override string TabHeader
    {
        get { return "Procurement"; }
    }
 }
```

Note that I override just one property. The rest of the properties should be taken from base ViewModel.

Now I want to display it by using this DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProcurementViewModel}">
    <views:DocumentView />
</DataTemplate>
```

But no data is shown. TabHeader is bound to Header of TabControl - it shows a value from base ViewModel.

If I specify DataType as `{x:Type vm:DocumentViewModel}` everything works just fine.

Here is a part of DocumentView, where I use DataTemplates:

```
<Grid>
    <telerik:RadTabControl Name="rtcTabs"  ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}" SelectedIndex="1">
        <telerik:RadTabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabHeader}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:RadTabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <telerik:RadTabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DashboardViewModel}">
                <views:DashboardView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProcurementViewModel}">
                <views:DocumentView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:RadTabControl.Resources>
    </telerik:RadTabControl>
</Grid>
```

Here is a part of DocumentView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DMRS.Views.DocumentView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DMRS.ViewModels;assembly=DMRS.ViewModels"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="358" d:DesignWidth="582" xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation">
<!--<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:DocumentViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>-->
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="stlDocViewCombobox" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="OpenDropDownOnFocus" Value="True"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <telerik:RadGridView AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="rgvData" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData}">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
..................................
```

Comment: I guess you create instance of ProcurementViewModel instead of DocumentViewModel.

Comment: could you show us the DataContext binding code of your contentControl  and the resource related to it ?

Comment: You do realize there is no `set` anymore right?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, that's what I want to achieve! I want to show data from ProcurementViewModel, not DocumentViewModel

Comment: @HichemC, I have Telerik's RadGridView, which is bound to Data collection: `<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" .../>`

Comment: @AndreyGordeev please provide more details and code so we can help on. people here don't have time to guess.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev The most important part is missing : I guess the DocumentView code behind, where are you setting the UserControl's DataContext

Comment: @HichemC, I guess I don't need it since I use DataTemplate. I have `VolunteeringViewModel` too, so I want 2 instances of DocumentView to show data from `ProcurementViewModel` and `VolunteeringViewModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I specify DataType as `{x:Type vm:DocumentViewModel}` everything
>   works just fine. TabHeader is bound to Header of TabControl - **it shows
>   a value from *base* ViewModel**.

It sounds like the item in your `DataContext` is actually a `DocumentViewModel`, not a `ProcurementViewModel`

An implicit `DataTemplate` for a base object should get applied to all objects that inherit from that type as well, however `DataTemplates` for a child object won't apply to a parent object.

So since you see the **base** `DocumentViewModel.TabHeader` when you set the `DataType="{x:Type vm:DocumentViewModel}"`, that means you are probably binding to a `DocumentViewModel` object, not a `ProcurementViewModel` object.

To confirm this is the case, you can use a 3rd party tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to find out what your `DataContext` object is at run-time.

**Edit:**

Based on the new code you added to your question, the most likely cause is your `Tabs` collection (the `DataContext` for the item applying the `DataTemplate`) does not contain a `ProcurementViewModel` object.

Can you check to be sure that your `Tabs` collection contains a `ProcurementViewModel` object, and doesn't just contain `DocumentViewModel` objects?

(Also since your `DataTemplates` are the same and `ProcurementViewModel` inherits from `DocumentViewModel`, you only need the `DataTemplate` for the `DocumentViewModel`)

Comment: Well, I believe this is expected behaviour when I see the base TabHeader when I bind to vm:DocumentViewModel. The question is how to bind DocumentView to ProcurementViewModel?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev You'll have to show us more code containing how the DataTemplate is used, and how the `DataContext` behind the template is set. It sounds like your `DataContext` is a `DocumentViewModel`, not a `ProcurementViewModel`, which is why your `DataTemplate` isn't getting applied. Change your `DataContext` to a `ProcurementViewModel` and it should work as you expect

Comment: @AndreyGordeev That's your problem then. It needs to be bound to a `ProcurementViewModel` that contains the modified `TabHeader` property , and to use the `DataTemplate` you have specified for a `ProcurementViewModel` :) How is the `DataContext` getting set?

Comment: I've updated my question. DataTemplate _already_ specified for a ProcurementViewModel

Comment: @AndreyGordeev A `DataTemplate` only tells WPF how to render an object - it doesn't create the object itself. Your `TabControl.ItemsSource` is bound to `{Binding Tabs}`, so if your `Tabs` collection contains a `ProcurementViewModel` object, then WPF will use the `DataTemplate` you specified for it when it tries to render the object. Can you check to be sure that your `Tabs` collection contains a `ProcurementViewModel` object, and doesn't just contain `DocumentViewModel` objects?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev (Also since your `DataTemplates` are the same and `ProcurementViewModel` inherits from `DocumentViewModel`, you only need the `DataTemplate` for the `DocumentViewModel`)

Comment: That's it! Thank you, Rachel. Could you update your answer? I'll mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

From the limited amount of information available to us, it looks as though this should work!  Check that the namespace for your derived VM is the same as the namespace of the base VM (or, if they are different on purpose, that you have an appropriate declaration for the namespace in XAML).

Another possibility is that you don't actually have any instances of `ProcurementViewModel` at runtime, so the `DataTemplate` is never used.  Double-check the runtime type of your VM instance here.

These things may sound obvious, but since this *ought* to work, you need to look for some small oversight in your code.

Answer (score 0):

One nice way to deal with this sort of problems is to inspect the DataContext property of the content control at runtime.

A good way to do that is to use a tool that you can inspect the bindings at runtime. For example, you can use the wpf inspector (http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/).