# WPF: Can't access the view. Datagrid is not refreshing with data in tabs

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm following this [How to create tab-able content in WPF/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547461/how-to-create-tab-able-content-in-wpf-c) but I want each tab to show a datagrid. The datagrid doesn't show and also doesn't show the data. When I step into the code, I do see 0,1 being set.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMDataInstances.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MVVMDataInstances"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate" 
                      DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ChildViewModel}"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TabControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate}"  
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
 public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> Items { get; private set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {

            Items = new ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> {new ChildViewModel(0), new ChildViewModel(1)};
        }
```

ChildView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVMDataInstances.View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:MVVMDataInstances"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:ChildViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
            <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Grid, Mode=TwoWay}" />

</UserControl>
```

ChildViewModel.cs

```
public class ChildViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ChildModel> _grid;

        public ObservableCollection<ChildModel> Grid
        {
            get { return _grid; }
            private set
            {
                _grid = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Grid");
            }
        }

        public ChildModel Data { get; set; }

        public ChildViewModel()
        {
        }

        public ChildViewModel(int tabNumber)
        {
            Data = new ChildModel {A = tabNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)};

            Grid = new ObservableCollection<ChildModel> {Data};
        }
    }
```

ChildModel.cs

```
public class ChildModel
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
    }
```

ViewModelBase.cs

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

I would like to see one grid per tab. The entry on the first tab has a value of 0 for property A. The entry of the second tab has a value of 1 for the property B.

I see that when OnPropertyChanged is called PropertyChanged is null.

I can access the datagrid if I have this in MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabTitle}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Grid}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

But OnPropertyChanged is always null for this and I don't see the grid

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate" 
                  DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ChildViewModel}">
     <viewModel:ChildView /> 
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow this [MVVM: ViewModel inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566742/mvvm-viewmodel-inheritance) to have ViewModel Inheritance. The reason PropertyChanged was null because the constructor was initialized twice. First time with an integer, and then second time with the InitializedComponent. If I comment out the InitializedComponent, the grid was never initialized. The answer to the other stackoverflow question makes everything cleaner with view model inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataTemplate` is empty.  From your question, you probably want to do something along these lines:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type viewModel:ChildViewModel}">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" . . .>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <!-- Your column definitions here -->
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TabControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate}"  
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This would set the headers but won't put value of 0,1 for Data as specified inside MainWindowViewModel.cs

Answer (score 0):

This DataTemplate tells the ChildViewModel.cs that it's appearance is View.xaml :

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate" 
                  DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ChildViewModel}">
     <viewModel:View /> 
</DataTemplate>
```

As a result behind the scenes it also sets each View's DataContext to an instance of      ChildViewModel.

Comment: I'm trying to use the example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547461/how-to-create-tab-able-content-in-wpf-c MainWindowViewModel.cs did create two tabs, but didn't show the grid. I don't know how to use ContentPresenter. I will look that up. The last snippet you provided doesn't work.

Comment: I see the outline of the datagrid now, but when I step through the code Property Change is always null.